# Restoring a domain machine which name is already in use

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2019

I have such situation: one of domain PCs was broken and replaced by new one using the same machine name. Now the old machine is back from service and I want to use it in different place, but if I try to authorize on it, I get an error that trust relations between workstation and domain are lost. There's no local account on this "old" PC. How do I restore the machine while not touching the new one?

Comment: `How do I restore the machine while not touching the new one?` Re-image it with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

As @grek-askew pointed out, reinstalling the OS is the easiest solution. If the machine left your company this would be advisable for security reasons anyway.

#### If reinstalling the OS is not an option

You could use a tool like [HBCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) to create a local admin account. Log in with that, leave the AD, and re-join with a different machine name.